# Make second level UL take 100% with special behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

I am trying to make a custom tree view to shop trough diverse categories on my website. You can see what I want to do [here on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hj0tgpLb/1/). I need the second level UL to take all the space under the current row of selected li without making other li of the row moving.

Here is my code

HTML:

```
<ul Class="CategoriesContainer">
<li Class="CategoryButton">
    <div class="UpperHalf">
        <span class="helper"></span>
        <img class="CategoryImage" src="http://cdn.1001freedownloads.com/icon/thumb/390973/shoes-icon.png"/>
    </div>    
    <div class="LowerHalf">

        <span class="CategoryText">Shoes</span>
    </div>  
    <ul Class="TreeContainer">
        <li>Man shoes</li>
        <li>Woman shoes</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li Class="CategoryButton">
    <div class="UpperHalf">
        <span class="helper"></span>
        <img class="CategoryImage" src="http://cdn.1001freedownloads.com/icon/thumb/390973/shoes-icon.png"/>
    </div>    
    <div class="LowerHalf">

        <span class="CategoryText">Shoes</span>
    </div>  
    <ul Class="TreeContainer">
        <li>Man shoes</li>
        <li>Woman shoes</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li Class="CategoryButton">
    <div class="UpperHalf">
        <span class="helper"></span>
        <img class="CategoryImage" src="http://cdn.1001freedownloads.com/icon/thumb/390973/shoes-icon.png"/>
    </div>    
    <div class="LowerHalf">

        <span class="CategoryText">Shoes</span>
    </div>  
    <ul Class="TreeContainer">
        <li>Man shoes</li>
        <li>Woman shoes</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li Class="CategoryButton">
    <div class="UpperHalf">
        <span class="helper"></span>
        <img class="CategoryImage" src="http://cdn.1001freedownloads.com/icon/thumb/390973/shoes-icon.png"/>
    </div>    
    <div class="LowerHalf">

        <span class="CategoryText">Shoes</span>
    </div>  
    <ul Class="TreeContainer">
        <li>Man shoes</li>
        <li>Woman shoes</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li Class="CategoryButton">
    <div class="UpperHalf">
        <span class="helper"></span>
        <img class="CategoryImage" src="http://cdn.1001freedownloads.com/icon/thumb/390973/shoes-icon.png"/>
    </div>    
    <div class="LowerHalf">

        <span class="CategoryText">Shoes</span>
    </div>  
    <ul Class="TreeContainer">
        <li>Man shoes</li>
        <li>Woman shoes</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li Class="CategoryButton">
    <div class="UpperHalf">
        <span class="helper"></span>
        <img class="CategoryImage" src="http://cdn.1001freedownloads.com/icon/thumb/390973/shoes-icon.png"/>
    </div>    
    <div class="LowerHalf">

        <span class="CategoryText">Shoes</span>
    </div>  
    <ul Class="TreeContainer">
        <li>Man shoes</li>
        <li>Woman shoes</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li Class="CategoryButton">
    <div class="UpperHalf">
        <span class="helper"></span>
        <img class="CategoryImage" src="http://cdn.1001freedownloads.com/icon/thumb/390973/shoes-icon.png"/>
    </div>    
    <div class="LowerHalf">

        <span class="CategoryText">Shoes</span>
    </div>  
    <ul Class="TreeContainer">
        <li>Man shoes</li>
        <li>Woman shoes</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li Class="CategoryButton">
    <div class="UpperHalf">
        <span class="helper"></span>
        <img class="CategoryImage" src="http://cdn.1001freedownloads.com/icon/thumb/390973/shoes-icon.png"/>
    </div>    
    <div class="LowerHalf">

        <span class="CategoryText">Shoes</span>
    </div>  
    <ul Class="TreeContainer">
        <li>Man shoes</li>
        <li>Woman shoes</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.CategoriesContainer{
width:90%;
display:Block;
list-style:none;
}
.CategoryButton{
    height:130px;
    width:130px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    background-color:lightgray;
     text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.helper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.UpperHalf {
    display:block;
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
}
.LowerHalf {
    display:block;
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
}
.CategoryImage
{
   height:40px;
   width:40px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.CategoryText {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
.TreeContainer {
    width:100%;
    display:none;

}
.Toggled
{
   left:0;
   top:0;
   padding:0; 
   margin:0; 
   white-space:nowrap;
   display:block;
   background-color:green;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(".CategoryButton").click(function () {
var Container = $(this).find(".TreeContainer")[0];
if ($(Container).hasClass("Toggled"))
{
    $(Container).removeClass("Toggled");
}   
else
{
    $(Container).addClass("Toggled");
}

});
```

Edit
[There](http://dropbox.com/s/foz7diwge2vfxo1/Mockup.png?dl=0) is a mock up of what I am trying to do.

Regards

Comment: try replacing code

.CategoryButton {
    background-color: lightgray;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    min-height: 130px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 130px;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the containers same row not moving down adding:

```
.CategoryButton{
    min-height: 130px;  
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

The problem now is that your sub-category won't be shown as you have given to the containers a fixed height (130px) while the 2 `divs` inside gets all the height (50% height each), so there's no room for your subcategory. It will be shown (overflow is visible) but won't move the elements below as the height of the container will always be 130px.

You may fix this changing the height to `min-height:130px;` and as the height is a fixed amount add `height:65px`to the elements inside. This way the container height will change when the subcategory is shown:

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hj0tgpLb/3/)**

Comment: We are close your solution is close of what I want to acheive but there is one thing left. I need the UL to take 100% of the parent UL under the selected li row. (I'm sorry my question was a bit confusing regarding that point) ex:

Comment: Cat Cat Cat(Selected) Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat            Selected UL -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat Cat

Comment: pardon?   cat cat cat does not man anything in my leguage (nor in english)

Comment: <li> <li> <li Class="Selected"> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> Selected UL --------------------------------------------------------------------------------‌​-----------------------------------------------------------<li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li>

Comment: man, I'm sorry but your comments makes no sense. You can't copy/paste in the comments section at all.

Comment: There is a mock up of what I am trying to acheive: https://www.dropbox.com/s/foz7diwge2vfxo1/Mockup.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You can add `float: left` to the `ul` elements and also add some `margin-bottom` to display them correctly:

```js
$(".CategoryButton").click(function() {
  var Container = $(this).find(".TreeContainer")[0];
  if ($(Container).hasClass("Toggled")) {
    $(Container).removeClass("Toggled");
  } else {
    $(Container).addClass("Toggled");
  }

});
```

```css
.CategoriesContainer {
  width: 90%;
  display: Block;
  list-style: none;
}
.CategoryButton {
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 40px;/*add margin-bottom*/
}
.helper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.UpperHalf {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
.LowerHalf {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
.CategoryImage {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.CategoryText {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.TreeContainer {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
.Toggled {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;/*add float left*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul Class="CategoriesContainer">
  <li Class="CategoryButton">
    <div class="UpperHalf">
      <span class="helper"></span>
      <img class="CategoryImage" src="http://cdn.1001freedownloads.com/icon/thumb/390973/shoes-icon.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="LowerHalf">

      <span class="CategoryText">Shoes</span>
    </div>
    <ul Class="TreeContainer">
      <li>Man shoes</li>
      <li>Woman shoes</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li Class="CategoryButton">
    <div class="UpperHalf">
      <span class="helper"></span>
      <img class="CategoryImage" src="http://cdn.1001freedownloads.com/icon/thumb/390973/shoes-icon.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="LowerHalf">

      <span class="CategoryText">Shoes</span>
    </div>
    <ul Class="TreeContainer">
      <li>Man shoes</li>
      <li>Woman shoes</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li Class="CategoryButton">
    <div class="UpperHalf">
      <span class="helper"></span>
      <img class="CategoryImage" src="http://cdn.1001freedownloads.com/icon/thumb/390973/shoes-icon.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="LowerHalf">

      <span class="CategoryText">Shoes</span>
    </div>
    <ul Class="TreeContainer">
      <li>Man shoes</li>
      <li>Woman shoes</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li Class="CategoryButton">
    <div class="UpperHalf">
      <span class="helper"></span>
      <img class="CategoryImage" src="http://cdn.1001freedownloads.com/icon/thumb/390973/shoes-icon.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="LowerHalf">

      <span class="CategoryText">Shoes</span>
    </div>
    <ul Class="TreeContainer">
      <li>Man shoes</li>
      <li>Woman shoes</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li Class="CategoryButton">
    <div class="UpperHalf">
      <span class="helper"></span>
      <img class="CategoryImage" src="http://cdn.1001freedownloads.com/icon/thumb/390973/shoes-icon.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="LowerHalf">

      <span class="CategoryText">Shoes</span>
    </div>
    <ul Class="TreeContainer">
      <li>Man shoes</li>
      <li>Woman shoes</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li Class="CategoryButton">
    <div class="UpperHalf">
      <span class="helper"></span>
      <img class="CategoryImage" src="http://cdn.1001freedownloads.com/icon/thumb/390973/shoes-icon.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="LowerHalf">

      <span class="CategoryText">Shoes</span>
    </div>
    <ul Class="TreeContainer">
      <li>Man shoes</li>
      <li>Woman shoes</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li Class="CategoryButton">
    <div class="UpperHalf">
      <span class="helper"></span>
      <img class="CategoryImage" src="http://cdn.1001freedownloads.com/icon/thumb/390973/shoes-icon.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="LowerHalf">

      <span class="CategoryText">Shoes</span>
    </div>
    <ul Class="TreeContainer">
      <li>Man shoes</li>
      <li>Woman shoes</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li Class="CategoryButton">
    <div class="UpperHalf">
      <span class="helper"></span>
      <img class="CategoryImage" src="http://cdn.1001freedownloads.com/icon/thumb/390973/shoes-icon.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="LowerHalf">

      <span class="CategoryText">Shoes</span>
    </div>
    <ul Class="TreeContainer">
      <li>Man shoes</li>
      <li>Woman shoes</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your solution can't resolve issue. I took  shoes as an example but there will be some categories with more sub categories and even sub-subcategories so a fixed margin-bottom is not the appropriate solution.

Comment: @AlexSamson This solution is for the html mark up provide in OP.